# How can I post to OpenGraph using php sdk

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-opengraph

I would like to post to my user's wall using php sdk and the new Open Graph is there a way or I shall stick to the typical 'feed' method?

Comment: JS SDK but doesnt work too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the following code to post actions on timeline using open graph actions and objects.

```
<?php
require "src/facebook.php";

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'=>'xxxxxxxxx',
    'secret'=>'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    'cookie'=>true
));

if(!$facebook->getUser())
{
    $url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope'=>'publish_actions'));
    echo "<script> top.location=\"".$url."\"; </script>";
    exit(0);
}

$params = array('article'=>'http://www.onlytipsandtricks.com.com/test.html','access_token'=>$facebook->getAccessToken());

$out = $facebook->api('/me/app_namespace:read','post',$params);

print_r($out);

?>
```

Comment: is the publish actions important? i've heard that when OpenGraph is configured to the App it includes the app posting actions...